# Error in Python-generated XML

Tags: java, python, xml, xstream

I'm generating some XML code with Python. This code counts the number of occurences of a word in a corpus and matches that word to a number (a probability distribution).

Here's a sample a little of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <root>
        <Durapipe type="int">1</Durapipe>
        <EXPLAIN type="int">2</EXPLAIN>
        <woods type="int">2</woods>
        <hanging type="int">3</hanging>
        <hastily type="int">2</hastily>
        <key type="int" name="27p">1</key>
        <localized type="int">1</localized>
        <Schuster type="int">5</Schuster>
        <regularize type="int">1</regularize>
        ....
    </root>
```

Here's the Python I'm using to generate this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import nltk.corpus
from nltk import FreqDist
import dicttoxml

#corpus
words = [w.decode('utf-8', errors='replace') for w in nltk.corpus.reuters.words()]
fd = FreqDist(words)
afd = dict(fd)

# special key for sum
afd['__sum__']=fd.N()

xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(afd)

f=open('frequencies.xml', 'w')
f.write(xml)
f.close()
```

I later ran the XML through XStream to convert it into a Java Map. Unfortunately, XStream cannot convert it due to an error in the XML code, on the occurence of the word 'key'. I can't find an error for the life of me. The XML Error looks like this:

[Fatal Error] frequencies.xml:1:27582: Element type "key" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : Element type "key" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

So I have three questions here: What is this error? How can I fix the XML? How can I modify the Python code to generate correct XML?

Sorry for the lengthy question, but I'm inexperienced in both Python and XML. Any help you can give would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like a use-case for JSON, rather than XML.

Comment: The obvious difference between `key` and the other tags is that it has a `name` attribute and they don't. What is that for?

Comment: Also, what's the error from XStream? Considering that you're using a library whose error messages are a selling point, it's probably worth posting them here.

Comment: Here's the error: "[Fatal Error] frequencies.xml:1:27582: Element type "key" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"."

Comment: It might be better to add the xstream error message to the body of your question rather than as a comment... Comments get folded, and we are more likely to see it in the question.

Comment: It seems xstream is complaining about a different `<key />` element than the one in your sample. Check what it looks at the exact position indicated (line 1, column 27582). You could use something like `cut -c 27580-27600 frequencies.xml` to help you.

Comment: Extremely late to this party, but this issue should be fixed in version 1.7.3 of dicttoxml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nltk.corpus.reuters.words()` returns a list that contains some "words" that can not be valid XML element names, for example, `.'"`.

When `dicttoxml()` encounters such a key in the `afd` dictionary it generates an element with the name "key" and with an attribute `name` containing the original (invalid) name, e.g.

```
<key type="int" name=".'"">1</key>
```

Clearly this is invalid XML and all XML parsers should (rightly) complain about it. `xmllint` does and you've found that XStream does too. `dicttoxml()` is not replacing characters such as double quotes (`"`) with `&quot;`. To work around this you can call `xml_escape()` on the keys before running `dicttoxml()` (see dict comprehension below):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import nltk.corpus
from nltk import FreqDist
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml, xml_escape

#corpus
words = [w.decode('utf-8', errors='replace') for w in nltk.corpus.reuters.words()]
fd = FreqDist(words)
afd = {xml_escape(k):v for k,v in fd.items()}

# special key for sum
afd['__sum__']=fd.N()

xml = dicttoxml(afd)

f=open('frequencies.xml', 'w')
f.write(xml)
f.close()
```

Comment: You are a beautiful human being.

Comment: Does it please you to believe that I am a beautiful human being?

Comment: I'll edit the question to show it